# get node name by partial text in javascript

Tags: javascript, tags

I need to seperate values before and after column(:).before column as key and after column as value

Ex:

Product Name: Product 15

Product code: 1234

if i search for product it should give product name and product code as key and product 15 and 1234 as value by using javascript

```js
var text1=document.documentElement.innerHTML;
 var res = text1.match(/Product/g);
 
 for(j=0;j<res.length;j++)
 {
    console.log(res[j]);  
 }
```

```html
   <li>Product name: Product 15</li>
   <li>product code: 1200</li>
   <span> product category : bag </span>
```

Comment: I stuck in getting parent node of the partial text.how can i get that ?.also how to get complete text .

Comment: node name will differ .

Comment: values will not be in same li or span it will differ.

Comment: Your question and explanation is unclear. Please clarify it properly. Also, I'll keep my answer as reference. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you do `document.documentElement.innerHTML;`, you are retrieving HTML string from DOM and searching it. If you do this, it is difficult to go back to parent node as you do not have a node relation. You should look for necessary elements you need to search and loop over them to search.

Also, `text1.match` will search the pattern in text and give you matching words. Hence, you are only getting `Product` and not full sentence. Instead, use `regex.test` to check if string has the necessary word/pattearn. Also, run it over individual text and not in complete HTML string as you need the parent node.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("li,span");
var regex = /product/i

for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
  var text = elements[j].textContent;
  if (regex.test(text)) {
    console.log(text);
  }
}
```

```html
<li>Product name: Product 15</li>
<li>product code: 1200</li>
<span> product category : bag </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var arr=[];
 $('li').each(function(item){var item_text = $(item).text().split(':'); arr.push({[item_text[0]]:item_text[1]})});

// show results
console.log(arr);
```

js

```
var options = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var arr=[];
Array.from(options).forEach(function(item){var item_text = item.innerText.split(':'); arr.push({[item_text[0]]:item_text[1]})})

// show results
  console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I am asking in javascript not jquery.

Comment: If you are already using jQuery, you can use `$.each`. You do not need `Array.from`

Comment: Thanks. Corrected